# How to fix git "credential-'cache store: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF ..."

Tags: git, github, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I'm familiar with git but i have an issue when pushing ASP.NET CORE MVC Web apps to a github repository

git credential-'cache store: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''

git credential-'cache store: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: Show us `git config --list --show-origin`

Comment: Is there a redundant quote `'`? Try to use `git config credential.helper 'cache [<options>]'`.Refer to [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache)

Comment: @XingZou I already tried this command, it didn't fix my issue. However, after updating git to the last version and restarting my computer, the push works again now even if i'm still getting these messages !